# MongoDB v4.2, Apply changes in aggregate pipline

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a large documents like that and want to trim `blabla:` from all documents.

```
[{
    "_id" : 1,
    "videoHistory" : [ 
        "blabla:FSFS", 
        "blabla:CZXC", 
        "ADSK", 
        "DAOW"
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "videoHistory" : [ 
        "blabla:POQW", 
        "blabla:QWEE", 
        "VCXV", 
        "FSGG"
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "videoHistory" : [ 
        "blabla:FSSS",
        "AVCK", 
        "DAOC"
    ]
}
]
```

**What I have did?**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {
        $and: [
        {'videoHistory.1': {$exists: true}},
        {videoHistory: { '$elemMatch': {'$regex': 'blabla:'} }},
    ]}},
    { "$set": {
        "videoHistory": { 
            "$map": { 
                "input": "$videoHistory", 
                "as": "vid", 
                "in": { "$ltrim": { input: "$$vid", chars: "blabla:" } } 
            } 
        } 
    }},
    { $project: {"videoHistory": 1}},
])
```

When I run the code, the result as expected, but it doesn't apply changes to documents, So my question how can i apply this to documents?

I'm using MongoDB V4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this aggregation just provides the projected result to somewhere for example to the client side or to the shell, but doesn't update the original documents. Try $[merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/). Based on the doc, you should use the MongoDB 4.4 to output to the same collection that is being aggregated.